# removing Invalid UTF-8 character - 0xfffe in PHP

Tags: php, utf-8, pcre

Any ideas how can I get rid of `0xfffe` character inside the string via PHP functions?

is something like that OK ? `preg_replace('/[\x{fffe}-\x{ffff}]/u', '', $string)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, just to let you know `preg_replace('/[\x{fffe}-\x{ffff}]/u', '', $string)` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

One note: 0xFFFE (wrong, see EDIT below -- actually it's ***0xFEFF***) is usually use as so-called Byte-Order Marker, which is an optional thing at beginning of file (and only there!) that indicates byte order of the contents. It is often included for things like XML files.
So it may be possible to only consider case of content starting with this value, and not worry about the rest.

EDIT: As pointed out by comment, it's 0xFEFF that's used as BOM (see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Byte_order_mark) for more), not 0xFFFE. So if it was intended BOM, it'd be either busted one, or decoder assumed wrong order (UTF-16 BE vs LE). But more likely is its use as invalid char marker; and if so, original question makes more sense. The only additional suggestion is that whoever is serving such content is probably using too limiting encoding (ascii, latin-1), and that service should ideally be fixed instead of having to deal with this on client side.

Comment: The character U+FFFE is a non-character that is illegal in transmitted text, though could be used internal to a program precisely because it's not a valid character. Whatever bytes would, in a given encoding, encode as U+FEFF is used as a BOM precisely because if it's interpreted the other way around it'll be U+FFFE which is illegal and hence not possibly ever correct.

Comment: Yes. I am aware of the reasons for it being chosen as BOM, and just suggested that perhaps one has leaked; if so, it has to come before any content.

Comment: Ah! Somehow managed to misread codes to be the same... hence confusion.

While it could just be incorrect decoding for UTF-16, more likely then is its use as indicator of invalid chars (Java codecs often use that for cases where character falls outside the range, like trying to encode characters outside ASCII/Latin-1 range)

Comment: It's not wrong... FEFF indicates BE and FFFE indicates LE. 

"Conversely, if the first two bytes are 0xFF, 0xFE, then the text stream may be assumed to be encoded as UTF-16LE"